# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string in minus query

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried executing the following query:

```
select to_date(SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT,'dd-MON-YY') 
from SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.RAVE_LND_SUBJ_VST_FRM
minus
select SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT 
from SMARTTRIAL_ODR_STAGE.LS_STG_SUBJ_VST_FRM;
```

but the following error is returned: `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

What could the problem be?

Comment: what is data type of SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT column? for minus the data type should be same in select statement.

Comment: In the source table i.e SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.RAVE_LND_SUBJ_VST_FRM its nvarchar2 and in the target table i.e SMARTTRIAL_ODR_STAGE.LS_STG_SUBJ_VST_FRM its Date

Comment: convert the date column SMARTTRIAL_ODR_STAGE.LS_STG_SUBJ_VST_FRM from LS_STG_SUBJ_VST_FRM table also in same format as you have done for other. and correct syntax is to_date(SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT,DD-MON-YYYY)

Comment: @PoojaPatil can you also post some sample data in the subj_vst_frm_vst_dt column.

Comment: @Phonetic_man : It has date values like :2000-01-03 00:00:00 and some null's

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. let me know if it gives correct output

```
select NVL(to_date(SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT,'DD-MON-YY') ,SYSDATE)
from SMARTTRIAL_ODR_LANDING.RAVE_LND_SUBJ_VST_FRM
minus
select to_date(NVL(SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT,SYSDATE),'DD-MON-YY') 
from SMARTTRIAL_ODR_STAGE.LS_STG_SUBJ_VST_FRM;
```

Comment: I have tried this solution. It still gives the same error. Is this because the column has some null values ?

Comment: what types of varchar values stored in SUBJ_VST_FRM_VST_DT column? are they following same format 'DD-MON-YYYY"? So you can use nvl also to convert the null into SYSDATE

Comment: The data in columns cannot be changed

Comment: I know but you specify the correct format in to_DATE function and convert the null.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data it seems that your nvarchar column contains date data in the following format (YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss).

The following query works for me.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-03 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;
```

So I am hopeful that the following query should work for you.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(subj_vst_frm_vst_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
FROM smarttrial_odr_landing.rave_lnd_subj_vst_frm 
MINUS 
SELECT subj_vst_frm_vst_dt 
FROM smarttrial_odr_stage.ls_stg_subj_vst_frm;
```

However, the above query will also contain the timestamp. If the column subj_vst_frm_vst_dt in the ls_stg_subj_vst_frm table does not contain a timestamp or if you dont want to compare the timestamp you can try the following query.

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(subj_vst_frm_vst_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')) 
FROM smarttrial_odr_landing.rave_lnd_subj_vst_frm 
MINUS 
SELECT TRUNC(subj_vst_frm_vst_dt) 
FROM smarttrial_odr_stage.ls_stg_subj_vst_frm;
```